# Java, threading example, making it sync better

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been doing Learning Java (Oracle Press Books), I'm learning threading. The examples run a bit different from the book. So far, that has been understandable. However this latest one it seems a bit strange. Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/tu0qajMF

The programs demonstrates communication with wait() and notify() between threads. It has an object, with two synchronized methods tick and tock. They simply display tick and tock. When running the example it should go "Tick Tock Tick Tock ..." it usually does do this. Yet sometimes it goes "Tock Tick Tock Tick."

Why is it doing this?

How can I change the code so it doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't doing any pre-sync before the threads start up, so it's a race on who gets to run first. You don't get to a synchronization point until the first join, so any of the two threads may have started up at that point.

Comment: I see, how would I do pre-sync? Please answer the second question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding some pre-sync, I discovered a way after about fifteen minutes of leaving it on my subconscious, making some posts on Facebook and then an idea came to me. It was far more simple to solve than I thought.

In the class TickTock, I added a member "boolean virginity=true," and made Tock wait if virginity is true, and Tick set virginity to false when it ran. So when MyThread is ran Tick always runs first - because the object both threads share has a variable which ensures Tock waits for Tick and there is no race.

Code here: http://pastebin.com/AHCvcNa8

I wouldn't have been able to solve this without an answer to my first question, so thanks, first question answerer.